# Microphone, not working after a lot of work!

Tags: audio

I'm having some problems with my headphones(i'm using a combo jack), if i reproduce song is there no problem for that, but if i try to use the mic, doesn't work! I've try with doing a override, and only one app can use the microphone and that is SimpleScreenRecorder, but i need the microphone for Skype,Discord or even TS3.

Do anyone have a idea?, if you help me, you are going to be my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to mess up my sound system. After a lot of searching I found that installing DKMS (`sudo apt-get install dkms`) and then going to the daily builds audio snapshot from the Ubuntu team https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages and downloading the latest package for Ubuntu 16.04 more or less did the trick. At least it restored my audio connections. ALSA was still messed up (and I had not used alsamixer before this on this particular machine) so I reset that by running `alsactl -d` Finally all was restored!

I think I spent about 5 hours trying to get sound sorted and only by rebuilding the sound stack in this way have I been able to use the likes of Skype, Telegram and web based meeting systems again!